# Plugin for Sublime text 2 LiveReload

Tags: sublimetext2

i dont know what to do.
I have installed LiveReload plugin in Sublime text 2 and extension 2.0.9, and when i click on the LiveReload icon, plugin dont want to work.Nothing at all.No alerts and messages about some errors.

What to do?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20691838/edit) your question to include exactly what you've done, any code involved, the **exact text** of any errors, and what the expected behavior should be. Please also include the operating system you're using and the browser. Basically, we should be able to recreate your entire situation with the information you include. As it stands now, there is no way anyone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not heard to a sublime plugin for it, however, I used the LiveReload App.

- Download LiveReload app
- Install it
- Add your project folder to the app
- Place the script that it gives you at the bottom of your html document
- LiveReload away!

Windows users like me use the app because it's easy to setup. Be warned it's buggy though in windows. However if your mac, I think it's a lot more stable, from my limited knowledge.

You can download the app here: http://livereload.com/

Comment: Take note that the [Live Reload App](http://livereload.com/) mentioned in this answer is [not affiliated (and incompatible)](http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/92749-sublime-text-2) with the [live reload Sublime plugin](https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2) mentioned in the question.